# How to access the sale.order fields from sale.order.line model a view Qweb

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I 'm doing a report in a Qweb view. But do not know how to access fields sale.order from sale.order.line . Maybe this question is very simple, but I 'm just 'm introducing Odoo . And I need help.

Here I show you how it's my view Qweb :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="sale.ticket_servicio">            
     <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">            
          <div class="page">
            <div class="header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-6">
                               <img src="#"/>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">    
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <p>Orden Number:<span t-field="o.name"></span></p> **(HERE NEED TO ACCESS TO ORDER NUMBER) e.x:SO003**
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <p>Partner: </p> **(HERE NEED TO ACCESS TO PARTNER NAME)**
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <p>NIU:  <span t-field="o.niu"></span></p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <p>Product name: <span t-field="o.product_id.name_template"></span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <p>Lot: </p> **(HERE NEED TO ACCESS TO LOT)**
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <p>Date order: </p> **(HERE NEED TO ACCESS TO DATE ORDER)**
                    </div>
            </div>             
          </div>
     </t>
</t>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a field called order_id in the sale.order.line model. Use this to get the fields of sale.order. Like

```
t-field="o.order_id.name"
```

Hope this will solve your problem. cheers